# Appending HTML to control and then adding an onclick event to one of the html objects?

Tags: html, onclick, controls

I have a sub that writes out a bunch of HTML inside of a literal control. Part of this HTML is an image that I would like to add an onclick event to. The onclick just needs to alert a string that I have available in the same sub. ONCE THE HTML GENERATING IS COMPLETE the string to return will also be complete. So it is at this point I would need to add the onlick event to the image. But how can I do so as it won't recognize the control at this point? Thanks guys.

/********** EDIT **********/

ok so, I changed things around and I just inserted the string for the image button last so that the string to return is complete. however when the html is inserted the string kind of screws it up because of punctuation. the string could contain any number of special characters :',;" etc.

here is the line of html in the vb.net codebehind

```
text = "<td style='background-color:#C8DBEC;width:31px;'><img style='cursor:pointer;' id='imgPrint' src='../images/Buttons/printerbtn.png' onclick='printTranscript(" + finalText + ");' /></td>"
```

so my question is.. how do I need to format the finalText so that it will pass through to the javascript call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should look like this:

```
text = @"<td style='background-color:#C8DBEC;width:31px;'><img style='cursor:pointer;' id='imgPrint' src='../images/Buttons/printerbtn.png' onclick='printTranscript(""" + finalText + @""");' /></td>"
```

I put doublequotes before and after finalText variable (inside the brackets), otherwise its value would be parsed in javascript like a varible name. I also had to place @ sign at the beginning of the both strings to be able to use doublequotes
(you can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JQuery? it makes it pretty simple

$('#target').html(""');

$('#imgPrint').click(function() {  printTranscript(" + finalText + "); });

I Just love JQuery

I did not test but it'll be something like that

Comment: well the HTML is created in the code-behind with vb.net. I tried registerstartupscript with jquery in it to append the html but it wasn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

Just bind a click event to your image.  Set your alert to the finalText and voila.

```
$("#imgPrint").click(alert(finalText));
```

OR

```
$("#imgPrint").click(printTranscript(finalText));
```

finalText can be stored as an alt or title on the image and then you can grab that with jQuery as well, or you can set it in a field with display none.

With the above code you don't need an onClick on the image.